# Bluetooth device proximity using RSSI

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I would like to figure out how to locate a device by its connection strenght(dBm). Even if this don't give me a direct location, it could give me a radius of the device to the phone or the other way around. So far i've been able to gather the device name and RSSI "strenght" however, its a dynamic data i'm getting. I would like an continuously update of how good the strenght is. So the part I'm stuck on is getting the correct values(ive got -72dbm and  -342654dbm form the tests) and i need updates every 3 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should really do is use the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/download.html), it will work the distance out for you.

The actual calculation is very complex and this Library has been used by a lot of people since Radius Networks created it. The link is for the website downloads, but you can use gradle too.

It's easy to use and probably exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for!